# Glue_version and python_version not working in terraform

Tags: aws-sdk, terraform, aws-glue

Hellow everyone,
I am using terraform to create the glue job. Now AWS Glue now supports the ability to run ETL jobs on Apache Spark 2.4.3 (with Python 3).
I want to use this feature. but whenever i am making changes it is throwing error.
I am using
aws-cli/1.16.184.
Terraform v0.12.6
aws provider 2.29

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "aws_glue_job_foo" {
glue_version = "1"
name = "job-name"
description = "job-desc"
role_arn = data.aws_iam_role.aws_glue_iam_role.arn
max_capacity = 1
max_retries = 1
connections = [aws_glue_connection.connection.name]
timeout = 5

command {
name = "pythonshell"
script_location = "s3://bucket/script.py"
python_version = "3"
}

default_arguments = {
"--job-language" = "python"
"--ENV" = "env"
"--ROLE_ARN" = data.aws_iam_role.aws_glue_iam_role.arn
}

execution_property {
max_concurrent_runs = 1
}
}
```

But it is throwing error to me,

Error: Unsupported argument
An argument named "glue_version" is not expected here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been released in [version 2.34.0 of the Terraform AWS provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2340-october-31-2019).

Answer (score 1):

This Terraform issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9524#issuecomment-548514467).

Terraform `aws_glue_job` now accepts a [`glue_version` argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/glue_job.html#glue_version).

### Previous Answer

With or without `python_version` in the Terraform `command` block, I must go to the AWS console to edit the job and set "Glue version". My job fails without this manual step.

### Workaround #1

This issue has been [reported and debated](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9524) and [includes a workaround](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9524#issuecomment-519603952).

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "etl" {
  name     = "${var.job_name}"
  role_arn = "${var.iam_role_arn}"

  command {
    script_location = "s3://${var.bucket_name}/${aws_s3_bucket_object.script.key}"
  }

  default_arguments = {
    "--enable-metrics" = ""
    "--job-language" = "python"
    "--TempDir" = "s3://${var.bucket_name}/TEMP"
  }

  # Manually set python 3 and glue 1.0
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws glue update-job --job-name ${var.job_name} --job-update 'Command={ScriptLocation=s3://${var.bucket_name}/${aws_s3_bucket_object.script.key},PythonVersion=3,Name=glueetl},GlueVersion=1.0,Role=${var.iam_role_arn},DefaultArguments={--enable-metrics=\"\",--job-language=python,--TempDir=\"s3://${var.bucket_name}/TEMP\"}'"
  }
}
```

### Workaround #2

Here is a [different workaround](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8526#issuecomment-490161140).

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "network" {
  name = "${local.name}-glue-job"

  template_body = <<STACK
{
  "Resources" : {
    "MyJob": {
      "Type": "AWS::Glue::Job",
      "Properties": {
        "Command": {
          "Name": "glueetl",
          "ScriptLocation": "s3://${local.bucket_name}/jobs/${var.job}"
        },
        "ExecutionProperty": {
         "MaxConcurrentRuns": 2
        },
        "MaxRetries": 0,
        "Name": "${local.name}",
        "Role": "${var.role}"
      }
    }
  }
}
STACK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like terraform uses `python_version` instead of `glue_version`

By using `python_version = "3"`, you should be using glue version 1.0. Glue version 0.9 doesn't support python 3.

Comment: I tried that and it updated to Python 3 but it did not update the glue version. So in result when ETL jobs run , i got error saying Python version not supported with glue .9 so I am guessing that we need to update glue version as well. Not sure how to do that. This is weired that using python_version ="3" works fine but it does not update glue and spark version.

Comment: I just checked code https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_glue_job.go 

it seems terraform has no support for `glue_version`. You may raise issue there.

Comment: It is giving error.So what do you suggest? Should I wait for this to support glue_version? Because it is not possible to update Python version without that?